# Display geojson on WMS images in openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson, php

Here actually am trying to achieve multipolygon on wms layer in openlayers 3. In this i'm calling a php file which is giving the output of geojson format but i don't have any idea where i'm doing .
I have checked my json list which works fine. I'm  not getting What is the thing i'm missing in javascript please help me on that. I have also tried the bbox strategy but that doesn't work too.

Check the plunker of it https://plnkr.co/edit/YEG6vCA8yvi3KNzVt2W6?p=preview

This the format i have in my database in geom field.

```
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
```

i just want it to convert in latlong form

Here is my javascript code of layers

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Single image WMS example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/build/ol.js"></script>

</head>
<body>    

    <div id="map" class="map"></div>

<script>    

var lulayer = 

  new ol.layer.Image({       

     source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({

          url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/vhy/wms',
          params: {
                LAYERS: 'layername'
          }                      

        })
        });

var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'layernamegeojson.php',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
  })
});

    var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [landuselayer , vector],

            view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([79.17436, 21.01668]),
                zoom: 13
                                }),

            target: 'map'
        });  


        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically I wanted to achieve this output in form of mutipolygon on WMS images by calling this `geojson.php` page output format into javascript.

Comment: Try to setup a minimal [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to show us your problem. And have a look to official [Geojson example](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/geojson.html), that could help you.

Comment: @oterral how can i upload shapefile into jsfiddle .i can explain you if u have any doubt  like i have map of landuse /landcover now on that one i wanted to show  area  of waterbodies ,builtup etc, and that will be highlighted through polygon so the result i'm getting through php in from of geojson geometry. That php page  result how can i show into my map.

Comment: @oterral hi i have created plunker  of it  check it https://plnkr.co/edit/YEG6vCA8yvi3KNzVt2W6?p=preview . in this one i'm trying to fetch the file of geojson but the output doesn't come. Please check where i'm doing wrong if u have any idea. Here i have copy paste the output of my php file in multipolygon.geojson

Comment: You need to defined the correct CRS of your data in  your GeoJSON file. And use a more recent version of Openlayers can't be bad.

Comment: @oterral i'm using 3.5.0 version of openlayers and i have check the crs of data in QGIS which was correct CRS WGS 84 EPSG:4326

Comment: No the data in your geojson file are clearly not in EPSG:4326, values of a coordinate in EPSG:4326 are between -180, 180 for longitude and -90,90 for latitude and a coordinate of your polygons is [311724.5570568, 2325396.5591672]. You need to find projection it is. I talk about the geojson file of your plunkr demo.

Comment: @oterral Actually the main problem is that i'm unable to convert the geometry data into latlong form . I try to use st_transform also it also gives the same . And geojson file is the output from php page I have just copy paste the result and change the ext. Thats it.

Comment: If you can tell me which projection (EPSG format) your data is using. I can modify your plunkr to make it works. Otherwise I can't help you.

Comment: It seems the projection is EPSG: 32644 . See https://plnkr.co/edit/vMZBjOlUcHjpoWMhErhX?p=preview

Comment: how did you got to know about this projection

Comment: I've searched for india projection on http://epsg.io. But I can't guarantee you it's the exact projection but it's one close to the real one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is "How can I display the result of my php file?", here is the piece of code:

```
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: '[path to your php file]/geojson.php',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
  })
});
map.addLayer(vector);
```

that comes from the [official example](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/modify-features.html?q=geojson)

UPDATE:

This is the solution if your GeoJSON is correctly formatted with the crs defined inside it or if the GeoJSON is in EPSG:4326, otherwise if no crs defined in the GeoJSON (like you) you need to define the data projection in the `ol.format.GeoJSON` constructor :

```
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: '[path to your php file]/geojson.php',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
        defaultDataProjection: 'EPSG:32644'
    })
  })
});
map.addLayer(vector);
```

Don't forget to include the proj4js library and the projection you use to your html page:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.14/proj4.js" ></script>
<script src="//epsg.io/32644.js"></script>
```

Comment: Here is a working jsfiddle with the geojson you give inline http://jsfiddle.net/00j1q339/2/   so if your PHP file returns a correct geojson the code upper should  works as expected.

Comment: updated my code . N done like you said but it doesn't show any error and any polygon on it. And i'm also receiving the php result like you did in your geojson form . Where i'm doing wrong can you please check it.

Comment: And when i paste my php page result on your fiddle then it works. is there anything i'm missing in my code

Comment: Do you have a url where I can access to this php file?

Comment: no its not on the server but i can you show the result of php file.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/00j1q339/3/ you check this result output. which is i'm receiving from php page

Comment: I know the results of PHP file works correctly. If the upper code doesn't work it's maybe because you can't acces to your php file. File path, network or  https headers problems. It could be a lot of things. I can't help you on this if I haven't access to the file through a url.

Comment: I am using same procedure to get geojson from php but i am facing problem with double quotes which comes from array ( i have got geojson from php as {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":"{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[84.7316718809388,19.0302775870258],[84.7342718809388,19.0388775870258]) where as when i run the sql command from the postgis interface the geojson comes like {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[81.1303718809389,16.3617775870258],[81.1277718809389,16.3566775870258],

Comment: {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","g‌​eometry":"{"type":"M‌​ultiPolygon","coordi‌​nates":[[[[84.....etc (from php interface )

Comment: {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","g‌​eometry":{"type":"Mu‌​ltiPolygon","coordin‌​ates":[[[[81.13 ....etc from the posgis interface

Comment: $geojson = array(
      'type'      => 'FeatureCollection',
      'features'  => array()

   );

  while($edge=pg_fetch_assoc($data)) {
   // echo $edge['taluk'];
        $feature = array(
          'type' => 'Feature',
          'geometry' => $edge['geometry'],
          'properties' => array(
           'taluk' => $edge['taluk'] ));
     array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);
   } echo stripslashes(json_encode($geojson));?>